# Angular - Testing / mocking subscriptions that use rxjs fromEvent

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

in my Angular component I have an object array of companies which is provided as via `@Input()`: When this is loaded (as it is derived from a HTTP request) I take the value and assign it to another variable  called `filteredList` that I use for an `*ngFor`.

The `*ngFor` is used in a select menu and I have a `@ViewChild` which is an HTML Text Input that when a keyup event happens I take the value of the input and filter the filteredList. I am capturing the keyup event using rxJS `fromEvent`

To simplify this is my HTML

```
<input id="companiesInput" #companyInput>

<mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="listBoxChange($event)">
  <mat-list-option
  *ngFor="let company of filteredList"
    [value]="company"
    [checkboxPosition]="'before'">
    {{company.displayName}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

and here is some of my component code... all works well!!

```
@Input() companyList: any[] = [];
private tagsSubscription: Subscription;
filteredList: any[] = [];

ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {
  if (changes.companyList.currentValue && changes.companyList.currentValue.length > 0) {
    this.filteredList = this.companyList;
  }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const tagsSource = fromEvent(this.companyInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      debounceTime(250),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((ev: any) => {
        return of(ev.target.value);
      })
    );

    this.tagsSubscription = tagsSource.subscribe((res: any) => {
      res = res.trim();
      if (res.length > 0) {
        this.filteredList = this.companyList.filter((company) => company.displayName.indexOf(res) > -1);
      } else {
        this.filteredList = this.companyList;
      }
    });
  }
```

Everything works great, but I need to test my code and this is where I fall short. Here is my test

```
describe('tagsSubscription', () => {
    it('should filter the available list of companies returned', () => {
      const dummyArray = [
        { id: 1, displayName: 'saftey io' },
        { id: 2, displayName: 'msa' },
        { id: 3, displayName: 'acme' }
      ];

      component.companyList = dummyArray;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      component.ngOnChanges({ companyList: { currentValue: dummyArray } });

      const fromEventSpy = spyOn(rxjs, 'fromEvent').and.returnValue(() => rxjs.of({}));
      const companiesInput = element.querySelector('#companiesInput');

      element.querySelector('#companiesInput').value = 'ac';
      companiesInput.dispatchEvent(generateKeyUpEvent('a'));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      companiesInput.dispatchEvent(generateKeyUpEvent('c'));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.filteredList.length).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
```

From logging out I can see that in my test the fromEvent is never raised and thus tagsSource.subscribe is never ran. I am doing something wrong, I thought about mocking the `fromEvent` in my test by adding the following line to the top of my event, like so

`const fromEventSpy = spyOn(rxjs, 'fromEvent').and.returnValue(() => rxjs.of('ac'))`;

this doesn't work either. Has anyone any experience of how to test fromEvent Observables with Angular and perhaps can tell me how I can get my test working?

Comment: Are you sure `ngAfterViewInit()` method is called automatically and you don't have to call it yourself?

Comment: I put a `console.log` in the `ngAfterViewInit()` to check that it is called and it is, so that isn't the issue

Comment: And is it called before or after you use `spyOn`?

Comment: The fromEvent isn't called when using the spyOn

Comment: `spyOn` won't trigger `ngAfterViewInit` call. Something else did. So the question is whether `ngAfterViewInit` is called before you override `fromEvent` or after that because it's probably called before that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, if `tagSource` is a property of the component,

```
@Input() companyList: any[] = [];
private tagsSubscription: Subscription;
filteredList: any[] = [];
tagSource: any;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.tagsSource = fromEvent(this.companyInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      debounceTime(250),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((ev: any) => {
        return of(ev.target.value);
      })
    );
 }
```

To test this property, create a mock input element and assign it to the `nativeElement`:

```
it('ngAfterViewInit():', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockInputElement = document.createElement('input');
    component.companyInput = {
        nativeElement: mockInputElement
    };
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    mockInputElement.value = 'example' // pass the input to test
    mockInputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
    tick(250); // pass the debounceTime
    expect(component.tagSource).toEqual('example');
}));
```

You can use this logic to test your component.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a `ViewChild` simply trigger it.

```js
const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#companiesInput'));
input.triggerEventHandler('keyup', {/* some data */});
```

---

If it's an input - simply mock it and add 2 methods

```js
const handler: Function | undefined;

companyInput.nativeElement.addListener = (eventName: string, eventHandler: Function) => {
  if (eventName === 'keyup') {
    handler = eventHandler;
  }
};
companyInput.nativeElement.removeListener = () => {};

// call your code to subscribe

if (handler) {
  handler('value1');
  handler('value2');
  handler('value3');
  handler('value4');
}
```